# Reading raw data file dlm

Tags: sas

I have problem reading in a raw data file. The problem is that some of inputs gets cut of because of the delimiter. Since one of the title has "\" in front of the real title, the Book_Title output is only "\". I was wondering if there is a way of ignoring those symbols.

Input:

```
0195153448;"Classical Mythology";"Mark P. O. Morford";"2002";"Oxford University Press"
085409878X;"\"Pie-powder\"; being dust from the law courts;John Alderson Foote";"1973";"EP Publishing"
```

The code:

```
data rating.books;
infile "&path\BX-Books.csv" dlm=';' missover dsd firstobs=2;
input   ISBN: $12.
            Book_Title: $quote150.
            Book_Author: $quote60.
            Year_Of_Publication: $quote8.
            Publisher: $quote60.;
run;
```

Output:

```
ISBN | Book-Title | Book-Author | Publisher | Publication-Year 
0195153448 | Classical Mythology | Mark P. O. Morford | Oxford University Press | 2002 
085409878X | \ | being dust from the law courts,"|  1973 | Missing value
```

Desired output:

```
     ISBN | Book-Title | Book-Author | Publisher | Publication-Year 
    0195153448 | Classical Mythology | Mark P. O. Morford | Oxford University Press | 2002 
    085409878X | Pie-powder being dust from the law courts |John Alderson Foote | EP Publishing | 1973
```

Comment: Can you clearly indicate how you want those two lines parsed?  Perhaps re-post the desired result using | as the delimiter.  Is the issue that it is using  the \ to escape the embedded `"` characters instead of doubling them as SAS expects?  If your string contains `He said "Hi"` SAS would write that to a delimited files as `"He said ""Hi"""`.  It looks that system is instead generating `"He said \"Hi\""`.

Comment: @Tom Hi I have added the desired output to my question.

Comment: Is your first line really missing the ending `"` on the last field?

Comment: @Tom No, it should be a " at the end. I missed it when I copied the input.

Comment: What is the rule for parsing the second line into 5 fields instead of 6 or 4?

Comment: @Tom in the first row in the file it says what it contains. (ISBN, book title, author, publisher, publication year) But I think it would be okay to have more or less if it works better.

Comment: What rule did you use to decide that the second row should be treated as 5 elements since there are 6 strings separated by semi-colons. Or 4 if you treat one of the quoted strings as having an embedded semi-colon. So how did you decide to split it the way you did?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not look like your source data is following any known pattern.

If you read it without the `DSD` option then it will treat the second line as having 6 fields.

```
085409878X;"\"Pie-powder\"; being dust from the law courts;John Alderson Foote";"1973";"EP Publishing"

v1=085409878X
v2="\"Pie-powder\"
v3=being dust from the law courts
v4=John Alderson Foote"
v5="1973"
v6="EP Publishing"
```

If you try to "fix" the escaped quotes

```
_infile_=tranwrd(_infile_,'\"','""');
```

then you will end up with only 4 fields.

```
085409878X;"""Pie-powder""; being dust from the law courts;John Alderson Foote";"1973";"EP Publishing"

v1=085409878X
v2="Pie-powder"; being dust from the law courts;John Alderson Foote
v3=1973
v4=EP Publishing
v5=
v6=
```

To get your desired output you could try removing the `\";` and the `"\"` strings.

```
_infile_=tranwrd(_infile_,'\";',' ');
_infile_=tranwrd(_infile_,'"\"','');
```

Which does make it read as you want.

```
085409878X; Pie-powder  being dust from the law courts;John Alderson Foote";"1973";"EP Publishing"

v1=085409878X
v2=Pie-powder  being dust from the law courts
v3=John Alderson Foote"
v4=1973
v5=EP Publishing
v6=
```

Not sure if that will generalize to other lines with extra quotes or extra semi-colons.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I have not had access to the computer. I like the last solution, the only problem is that it is not working when I use _infile_=tranwrd(_infile_,'"\"',''); (Nothing happens) But when I change and make into a variable infile_=tranwrd(_infile_,'"\"',''); it does what it is suppose to do but it makes it a variable instead. Is it possible to split up that variable instead.

Comment: The automatic `_infile_` variable requires an extra `input @;` statement first to get it populated.  Then you try to modify it and then run your `INPUT` statement. Perhaps that is your issue?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change a bit your code to put the missing column into a string **$150.** like that :

```
data work.books;
infile "h:\desktop\test.csv" dlm=';' missover dsd firstobs=1;
input   ISBN: $12.
            Book_Title: $150.
            Book_Author: $quote60.
            Year_Of_Publication: $quote8.
            Publisher: $quote60.;
run;
```

Then, you have to **clean** the column from special characters " and \ with this macro function :

```
%macro cleaningColumn(col);
    compress(strip(&col),'\"',' ')
%mend cleaningColumn;
```

You can include the macro function into a proc sql statement like this :

```
proc sql;
create table want as
    select 
        ISBN,
        %cleaningColumn(Book_Title) as Book_Title,
        Book_Author,
        Year_Of_Publication,
        Publisher
    from books;
run;
```

The column Book_Title will be like this :

```
Classical Mythology
Pie-powder
```

Regards,